# influxdb data is showing in grafana but graph is not showing

Tags: influxdb

query used in grafana to get data:SELECT value FROM "cpu_load_short" and
response from influxdb is {"results":[{"series":[{"name":"cpu_load_short","columns":["time","value"],"values":[["2016-06-17T06
:23:39.3855934Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T07:10:54.1543272Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:21:43.8362874Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08
:30:54.2708891Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:38:06.8087172Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:38:40.659661Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08
:38:46.0169674Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:38:57.2826142Z",0.64],["2016-06-20T08:44:40.7810414Z",0.64]]}
but grafana graph is not showing
]}]}

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is that you're asking. How can I help?

Comment: I am having the same issue

http://i.stack.imgur.com/ABMnY.png

I'm using Telegraf 0.13.1, InfluxDB0.13.0 and Grafana 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.1

I can see data coming in but it does not display any graphs

Comment: Forgot to add that I don't have this issue on CentOS 7.

Comment: I've been bitten by time zones - looking in the wrong portion of a Grafana chart because my brain mixed up the local TZ showing on the chart and the UTC in the data. Could that be the case here?